# How to have 4% width of watermark 100% width of images FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to add watermark to an image of all sizes.

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i evercam-white-logo.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10' junaidholy.jpg
```

which works fine in adding watermark to image but it fails on different size of images such as

[image]

And then I have an image as

[image]

I want to add watermark such as

- 4% width of the complete image width (100%)
- 15px spacing from left and bottom for logo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scale2ref` filter.

`ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i evercam-white-logo.png -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref=iw*4/100:ow/mdar[wm][video];[video][wm]overlay=x=W-w-15:y=main_h-overlay_h-15' junaidholy.jpg`

Comment: the above command in question add a logo to right bottom, but its adding in left?

Comment: I mean can you edit to add logo watermark to right bottom?

Comment: Edited command.

Comment: Thanks, I am accepting it just a question: Do you think it will be 15px from left and botton of the logo?

Comment: That was my first version. Check the earlier edit.

Comment: is it possible to change 15px to 1.2% instead?

Comment: `=W-w-W*1.2/100`

Comment: Great also for y? it will be the same?

Comment: `main_h-overlay_h-1.2/100*H`